# How to pass a class type, that conforms to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to make a generic sterilizer function using SwitfyJson.
Currently every where I'm getting server response, I'm parsing is like this:

```
       let json = JSON(data : networkResponse.data!)
        let usersJson = json["data"]
        var users = [User]()

        for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in usersJson {
            let user = User(json: subJson)
            users.append(user)
        }
```

Now this is repeatedly every were I'm getting a response. 
I'm trying to use a generic function insted. It should look somthing like this:

```
    protocol Serializable {
        init(json: JSON)
    }

       func serializeToArray(data: NSData, serializable:  Serializable)->serializable {

            let json = JSON(data : data)
            let jsonObjects = json["data"]
            var serializedObjects = [serializable.classType]()

            for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in jsonObjects {
                let serializedObject = User(json: subJson)
                serializedObjects.append(user)
            }

              return serializedObjects
        }
```

But this "classType" is not available in Swift.
Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your serialize-method use a generic type.
It looks like you only need the type of the array.

```
func serializeToArray<SerializableType : Serializable>(data: NSData, serializableType:  SerializableType.Type)-> [SerializableType] {
    // stuff
    var serializedObjects = [SerializableType]()
    // more stuff
    return serializedObjects
}
```

This way, you can pass your type to the function without needing to instantiate an object first:

```
let users = serializeToArray(data: data, serializableType: User.self)
```

The returned result will then be of the type `[User]`

Comment: Thanks, Great answer! I've just changed the Generic name to 'T' for better readability "static func serializeToArray<T: Serializable>(data: NSData, _:  T.Type)->[T]  "

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is more what you're looking for:

```
static func serializeToArray(json:[String:AnyObject]) {
    var serializedObjects = [Serializable]()
    guard let jsonArray = json["data"] as? Array<[String:AnyObject]> else {
        return [Serializable]()
    }

    for jsonDict in jsonArray {
        serializedObjects.append(Serializable(init:jsonDict)) 
   }

    return serializedObjects
}
```